# Some images cannot be decoded

Tags: android, xamarin

I have a very simple code in my push handler:

```
var bitmapStream = new URL(bitmapUrl)?.OpenConnection()?.InputStream;

var bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeStream(bitmapStream);
```

But some images cannot be decoded, e.g. this URL looks totally fine in the browser and I can open the image with every editor:

https://notifo-dev.easierlife.com/api/assets/proxy?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.pngkey.com%2Fpng%2Ffull%2F441-4415658_disney-christmas-png-mickey-and-minnie-christmas-png.png&width=192&height=192&bg=white

But it just returns null and no information is given about the problem. I am running on Windows using the Simulator: Nexus 5, API 29

I thought it could be the transparent background and therefore added the `bg=white` query string, which requests my API to add a background color. But this was not the root cause.

I cannot test the original image in Android, because it always gives me a "NotFound" exception. Not sure why, perhaps the agent is blocked.

Is there an option to get more error deteails, and not just "null".

Comment: that url returns a 302

Comment: @Jason, No, that link returns Donald D.

Comment: when I tested it with `curl` it appeared to return a 302

Comment: Perhaps it was a temporary backend issue. In this case it redirects to a fallback image.

Comment: if it **redirects** to a fallback image, then I was right.  **302** is a redirect status code.  Your web browser will handle a redirect automatically, while a Http request in code will not.

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was not the decoding. The source server has blocked Android agents and in my proxy I was forwarding the User-Agent header. Without the header the image is server just fine and shown correctly.